# If reset vector is hardwired, why start Start Segment Address is present in binary?

Tags: x86, reset

I am working on 80186XL processor based embedded system. This system doesn't have any BIOS or OS. 
If reset vector is hardwired at physical address FFFF0h, then why "Start Segment Address" Record type appears in binary (in Intel hex format). 
The following are last 4 lines of binary 
:02000002FFFFFE 
:05000000EA0000D0FF42 
**:04000003FFD000002A** 
:00000001FF

Regards, 
Ajith

Comment: It writes a JMP instruction at the reset address, the EA opcode is JMP, it jumps to FFD0:0000h.  The real start address, your program needs to be located there or it isn't going anywhere.  Including this info in the hex file isn't necessary on your hardware, it isn't wrong.

Comment: @Hans Passant : I understand the opcode present at reset vector and its usage, but why start segment address opcode is present :04000003FFD000002A